# How to get rid of GVim folding comments in your code?

Tags: c, vim, vi

There is someone in my team that swears by using some kind of GVim feature to do manually code folding.

As I'm using another editor and do not really need the folding feature, I think it only pollutes the source code with tags like:

```
/* {{{1 */
```

Convincing the person not to use this folding is not an option (got into some heated discussions before).

I'm not really a GVim guy, I'm wondering if there are not any other ways to do the folding without changing the team's code?

- Maybe putting the folding directions in a separate file, or
- Doing some kind of smart folding that takes the syntax of the programming language into account without changing the source code?

Comment: It's not pollution, it's something that you don't like.

Comment: No, I still think it's pollution, but you may think otherwise ;-). The point is that if every developer in your team comes up with their own way of commenting source code, you end up with pollution one way or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only took a Google for "vim folding" to [discover](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/fold.html) that Vim supports six fold methods.

`syntax`, `indent` and `diff` all mean that the user has little control over where the folding happens. That may or may not be a problem.

`marker` is a problem for you because you don't like the markers.

`expr` had a little of each of those problems, depending on the expression you create.

If your man wants to define his own fold points, and store them in an separate file, it seems like `set foldmethod=manual` combined with `:mkview` and `:loadview` would do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I would imagine he could just add the following to his .vimrc:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
```

Assuming he is using a version of VIM that supports that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try it yourself.  Once you start using foldmethod=marker there is just no going back.  I am working on a project now where I can't use marker folding and it feels like washing clothes in a time before there were washing machines.